Image resizing can be the problem for bad performances?
I am trying to train an EfficientNetB3 classifier on a set of custom images. I processed these images on Roboflow and as a preprocessing step I did:

Resize: Stretch to 300x300 (300 is the useful image size for EfficientNetB3).

Now I download my images and try this code to train the network:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications import EfficientNetB3
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

ROOT_DIR_CLASS = "/data/dataset/classifier_dataset/"

IMG_SIZE = 300  
BATCH_SIZE = 256
NUM_CLASSES = 3

dataset_class = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR_CLASS)
contents = os.listdir(dataset_class)

class_labels = []

for item in contents:
  all_classes = os.listdir(ROOT_DIR_CLASS + '/' + item)
  for i in all_classes:
    class_labels.append((item, str('dataset_path' + '/' + item) + '/' + i))

# Build a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=class_labels, columns=['Labels', 'image'])

dataset_path = os.listdir(ROOT_DIR_CLASS)

images = []
labels = []

# Resize the images
for i in dataset_path:
    data_path = ROOT_DIR_CLASS + str(i)
    filenames = [i for i in os.listdir(data_path) ]

    for f in filenames:
        img = cv2.imread(data_path + '/' + f)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        images.append(img)
        labels.append(i)

# Normalization phase
images = np.array(images)
images = images.astype('float32') / 255.0
images.shape

# Label encoding
y=df['Labels'].values
y_labelencoder = LabelEncoder ()
y = y_labelencoder.fit_transform (y)

y=y.reshape(-1,1)

ct = ColumnTransformer([('my_ohe', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
Y = ct.fit_transform(y) #.toarray()

images, Y = shuffle(images, Y, random_state=1)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(images, Y, test_size=0.05, random_state=415)

def build_model(num_classes):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
    x = inputs
    model = EfficientNetB3(include_top=False, input_tensor=x, weights="imagenet")

    # Freeze the pretrained weights
    model.trainable = False

    # Rebuild top
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(model.output)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    top_dropout_rate = 0.2
    x = layers.Dropout(top_dropout_rate, name="top_dropout")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax", name="pred")(x)

    # Compile
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="EfficientNet")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    return model

model = build_model(num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)

def plot_hist(hist):
    plt.plot(hist.history["accuracy"])
    #plt.plot(hist.history["val_accuracy"])
    plt.title("model accuracy")
    plt.ylabel("accuracy")
    plt.xlabel("epoch")
    plt.legend(["train", "validation"], loc="upper left")
    plt.show()

#plot_hist(hist)

preds = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
print ("Loss = " + str(preds[0]))
print ("Test Accuracy = " + str(preds[1]))

epochs = 30
#hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, verbose=2)
hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, epochs = epochs, verbose = 2)
plot_hist(hist)

def unfreeze_model(model):
    # We unfreeze the top 20 layers while leaving BatchNorm layers frozen
    for layer in model.layers[-20:]:
        if not isinstance(layer, layers.BatchNormalization):
            layer.trainable = True

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

unfreeze_model(model)

epochs = 4  # @param {type: "slider", min:4, max:10}
hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, epochs = 5, verbose = 2)
plot_hist(hist)

model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)

model.save('/path/saved_models/efficientnet_model_unfreeze_256.h5')


But the training starts with an accuracy of 0.40, and after 30 epochs it maxes out at 0.42--so it's really bad. I was wondering whether this performance might depend on this preprocessing stage or not. If not, what could be the problem?
